# Make the sun disk visible?

Tags: lighting

I'm working on an outer space scene with a HDRi star texture and while I'm happy with the sun settings (direction, intensity, angle), I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make the sun disk itself visible.

A Google search results in a link to the Blender manual, but there's nothing in there regarding the sun disk itself. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/lighting/sun_position.html

Can the sun disk be made visible? or is there a workaround? Thanks. Blender 3.01, Windows 11

Comment: no you can't, you need to use another object like a sphere or a circle, and give it an Emission node

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! Another question: Is there a quick way to align an object to the sun's position? Or is that a trial & error process?

Comment: if you want to put it at the same position, select the sun object, then Shift S > Cursor to Selected, select the sphere you've created and Shift S again > Selection to 3D Cursor, but actually the sun location doesn't count so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I guess what I mean is if I have a sun light object with a solar azimuth of 150 degrees and an elevation of 130 degrees relative to the scene's ground plane, is there a way to quickly place an object, a suitable distance away, at that position in the sky? Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, if you're talking about the sun object itself, contrary to, for example, a point light, its location doesn't count, only the rotation (and all the parameters you'll find in the Object Data panel of course). You can place the sun wherever you want in the scene, it's considered to be infinitely far away, and its rays are parallel

Comment: I'm having success by creating an emissive sphere to serve as the visible sun, placing it sufficiently far away from the center of the scene to be at near-infinity, and then using the directional indicator of the sun light object to align the position of the emissive sphere. Close enough for my purposes.

Comment: You could also make a sun part of the HDRI image, this way it will always look far away

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a light visible as an object in render, you need to use another object like a sphere or a circle, and give it an *Emission* node.